# spring and interfaces

Tags: java, spring

I read all over the place about how Spring encourages you to use interfaces in your code. I don't see it. There is no notion of interface in your spring xml configuration. What part of Spring actually encourages you to use interfaces (other than the docs)?

Comment: In addition to the points raised about DI, things like Spring remoting are totally dependent on using interfaces.

Comment: That is a very good question.  And as you can see from the answers so far, noone has given a specific answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you define an interface for your classes, it helps with dependency injection. Your Spring configuration files don't have anything about interfaces in them themselves -- you just put in the name of the class.

But if you want to inject another class that offers "equivalent" functionality, using an interface really helps.

For example, saying you've got a class that analyzes a website's content, and you're injecting it with Spring. If the classes you're injecting it into know what the actual class is, then in order to change it out you'll have to change a whole lot of code to use a different concrete class. But if you created an `Analyzer` interface, you could just as easily inject your original `DefaultAnalyzer` as you could a mocked up `DummyAnalyzer` or even another one that does essentially the same thing, like a `PageByPageAnalyzer` or anything else. In order to use one of those, you just have to change the classname you're injecting in your Spring config files, rather than go through your code changing classes around.

It took me about a project and a half before I really started to see the usefulness. Like most things (in enterprise languages) that end up being useful, it seems like a pointless addition of work at first, until your project starts to grow and then you discover how much time you saved by doing a little bit more work up front.

Comment: While what you say is correct, it is not spring-centric.  It is java-centric.

Answer (score 34):

The [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) explains this well. In particular, figure 4.

> A. High level modules should not depend on low level modules. Both should depend upon abstractions.
>
> B. Abstraction should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions.

Translating the examples from the link above into java:

```
public class Copy {
    private Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(); // concrete dependency
    private Printer printer = new Printer();    // concrete dependency
    public void copy() {
        for (int c = keyboard.read(); c != KeyBoard.EOF) {
            printer.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Now with dependency inversion:

```
public class Copy {
     private Reader reader; // any dependency satisfying the reader interface will work
     private Writer writer; // any dependency satisfying the writer interface will work
     public void copy() {
        for (int c = reader.read(); c != Reader.EOF) {
            writer.write(c);
        }
     }
     public Copy(Reader reader, Writer writer) {
         this.reader = reader;
         this.writer = writer;
     }
}
```

Now `Copy` supports more than just copying from a keyboard to a printer.

It is capable of copying from any `Reader` to any `Writer` without requiring any modifications to its code.

And now with Spring:

```
<bean id="copy" class="Copy">
    <constructor-arg ref="reader" />
    <constructor-arg ref="writer" />
</bean>

<bean id="reader" class="KeyboardReader" />
<bean id="writer" class="PrinterWriter" />
```

or perhaps:

```
<bean id="reader" class="RemoteDeviceReader" />
<bean id="writer" class="DatabaseWriter" />
```

Answer (score 11):

Most of the answers here are some form of "You can easily swap out implementations", but what I think they fail to answer is the why? part.  To that I think the answer is almost definitively testability.  Regardless of whether or not you use Spring or any other IOC framework, using Dependency Injection makes your code easier to test.  In the case of say a writer rather than a PrinterWriter, you can Mock the Writer interface in a Unit test, and ensure that your code is calling it the way you expect it to.  If you depend directly on the class implementation, your only option is to walk to the printer and check it, which isn't very automated.  Furthermore, if you depend upon the result of a call to a class, not being able to Mock it may prevent you from being able to reach all code paths in your test, thus reducing their quality (potentially)  Simply put, you should decouple Object graph creation from application logic.  Doing so makes your code easier to test.

Comment: I haven't seen any evidence to support the claim of unit testing improves software quality/reliability/speed.

Comment: I'd much rather use Mockito than write and maintain a bunch of interfaces.

Comment: @mrog mockito creates mock implementation for your interface?

Comment: @LokeshaS Mockito creates mock implementations for my classes.  I don't usually need to create separate interfaces, but Mockito can mock those, too.

Comment: @mrog, It does create mocks for classes but the question is why do we need interfaces.The answer is to prevent tight coupling between layers, tight coupling between classes(a service can use other service) and lastly to separate implementation from abstractions. Generally the argument is we never have second implementation then why do we need interfaces. My answer is we do have second implementation in the form of stubs/mocks. Remember writing testable code is one of the aspects of software development. So saying never had second implementation isn't true.

Comment: @LokeshaS Sure, the mocks use an interface, but it's not an explicit interface, it's the implicit interface that's automatically included with every class.  My point is that Mockito works perfectly without needing to write separate interfaces for every class.

Comment: @mrog, It works perfectly for sure but then the purpose of interfaces is to provide other aspects as i have mentioned in the my previous reply. Using cglib you can avoid interfaces and proxy  it but then the purpose is different with interfaces.

Comment: @LokeshaS My point is that you don't need to add interfaces for testability, and adding them for that reason alone is counterproductive.  But if you have a production use case that would benefit from multiple implementations, then go right ahead.

Answer (score 6):

No one has mention yet that in many occasions won't be necessary to create an interface so that the implementing class can be switched quickly because simply there won't be more than one implementing class.

When interfaces are created without need, classes will be created by pairs (interface plus implementation), adding unnecessary boilerplate interfaces and creating potential dependency confusions because, on XML configuration files, components will be sometimes referenced by its interface and sometimes by its implementation, with no consequences at runtime but being incoherent regarding code conventions.

Answer (score 2):

You may probably want to try using it for yourself to be better able to see this, it may not be clear from the docs how Spring encourages interface use.

Here are a couple of examples:

1. Say you're writing a class that needs to read from a resource (e.g., file) that may be referenced in several ways (e.g., in classpath, absolute file path, as a URL etc). You'd want to define a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` (interface) property on your class. Then in your Spring configuration file, you simply select the actual implementation class (e.g., `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource`, `org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource`, `org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource` etc). Spring is basically functioning as an extremely generic factory.
2. If you want to take advantage of Spring's AOP integration (for adding transaction interceptors for instance), you'll pretty much need to define interfaces. You define the interception points in your Spring configuration file, and Spring generates a proxy for you, based on your interface.

These are examples I personally have experience with. I'm sure there are much more out there.

Answer (score 2):

it's easy to generate proxies from interfaces.

if you look at any spring app, you'll see service and persistence interfaces.  making that the spring idiom certainly does encourage the use of interfaces.  it doesn't get any more explicit than that.

Answer (score 2):

Writing separate interfaces adds complexity and boilerplate code that's normally unnecessary.  It also makes debugging harder because when you click a method call in your IDE, it shows the interface instead of the implementation.  Unless you're swapping implementations at runtime, there's no need to go down that path.

Tools like Mockito make it very easy to test code using dependency injection without piling on interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Spring won't force you to use interfaces anywhere, it's just good practice. If you have a bean that has a some properties that are interfaces instead of concrete classes, then you can simply switch out some objects with mockups that implement the same interface, which is useful for certain test cases.

If you use for example the Hibernate support clases, you can define an interface for your DAO, then implement it separately; the advantage of having the interface is that you will be able to configure it using the Spring interceptors, which will allow you to simplify your code; you won't have to write any code cathing HibernateExceptions and closing the session in a finally segment, and you won't have to define any transactions programmatically either, you just configure all that stuff declaratively with Spring.

When you're writing quick and dirty apps, you can implement some simple DAO using JDBC or some simple framework which you won't end up using in the final version; you will be able to easily switch those components out if they implement some common interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't use interfaces you risk an autowiring failure**:
Sometime Spring creates a Proxy class for a Bean. **This Proxy class is not a child class of the service implementation** but it re-implements all of its interfaces.
Spring will try to autowire instances of this Bean, however this Proxy class is incompatible with the Bean class. So declaring a field with Bean class can lead to "unsafe field assignement" exceptions.

You cannot reasonably know when Spring is going to Proxy a service (nor should you), so to protect yourself against those surprises, your best move is to declare an interface and use this interface when declaring autowired fields.