# Spring application has Cglib2AopProxy warnings

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions

Upon starting my application, I get numerous warnings along the lines of `o.s.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy 'Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.'` for about a dozen or so functions.

Now I perfectly understand that proxy-based aspects cannot be applied to final methods. However, I did not (on purpose, at least) try to weave any aspects into `JdbcDaoSupport`. I suspect it comes from `<tx:annotation-driven />`. Is there anything I can do to silence these warnings or, better yet, exclude those classes from the aspect weaving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have extended `JdbcDaoSupport` and added `@Transactional` annotations.

You can set the `Cglib2AopProxy` logger to log level ERROR to avoid the warn messages. For example if using log4j and log4j.properties:

```
log.logger.org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy = ERROR
```

Comment: Silencing it this way is a bit too unspecific. The warning in itself may be quite helpful.

Answer (score 16):

This is most likely caused by the `@Transactional` annotation, Spring wraps your DAO in a proxy to add the transactional behavior.

I would recommend to make your DAO implement an Interface (**create and use an interface for your DAO**), this will allow Spring to use a JDK dynamic proxy instead of having to use CGLib.

> Using CGLIB has a limitation that methods marked as final in target class can’t be advised as final methods can’t be overridden (CGLIB creates a subclass of target class at runtime) but this limitation disappears in case of using JDK dynamic proxies.

[Reference](http://thecafetechno.com/tutorials/spring/spring-proxying-mechanisms/)

Comment: I am quite aware of the proxy problem, as stated in the question. However, I do not use `JdbcDaoSupport` anywhere. All my repositories (save one) use Spring Data and thus must be interfaces anyway. I have to research whether the remaining one is the culprit or Spring Data itself or perhaps the custom implementation that extends one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use interfaces for dependency injection, the most reasons for this are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922135/why-always-have-single-implementaion-interfaces-in-service-and-dao-layers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899372/spring-why-do-we-autowire-the-interface-and-not-the-implemented-class).

You can read [documentation about proxying mechanic](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop) for details why you see this warning.

And please vote for [feature request of inspection for IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145408) that may helps us to avoid this warnings. BTW It also contains a good explanation.

Comment: I do not agree with „You should use interfaces for dependency injection“, and the references you quote are from 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot now uses CGLIB proxying by default, including for the AOP support. If you need interface-based proxy, you’ll need to set the spring.aop.proxy-target-class to false.

spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false