# Java spring interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, interface, dependency-injection

Based on pointers I got here at so, I decided using spring framework for the database interaction in this java tool I want to build

I notice the web tutorials ask that I create an interface for every table in the database and then a class that implements that interface

Is this really a spring framework need? If so, what is the thought ? Since the interface seems so specific to the class, not sure what reusability could be achieved by defining the contract?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the reference for "the web tutorials ask that I create an interface for every table in the database"?

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/jdbc/spring-jdbctemplate-example/

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm

Comment: Why do I feel your response has the makings of a 'no interfaces are not required by spring ... Duh!'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [spring and interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256255/spring-and-interfaces)