# Why interface is created

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i am new to spring

in my spring web project DAO and service they created the interface and implementing it created class. can we liminate interface.

Comment: why you want to eliminate interface?

Comment: Interface gives you flexibility, in case in future you want to pass it with some different implementaion.

Comment: @Sangam.R, It's a design pattern. Please check about the design pattern https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256255/spring-and-interfaces

Comment: A better explanation to it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256255/spring-and-interfaces).

Comment: It seems that you need to go through Java Core and design patterns first because it seems you still cannot understand why interfaces are required overall in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using interface is to create abstraction. When you call you DAO from Service, your service is not aware of the actual implementation of DAO/ cases in which you have multiple implementations of your DAO interface, your service is not aware of the actual impl being used.

With spring you will use - Autowire to inject the dependency. You will refer your Dependency using interface.

```
    @Component/@Service
    class ServiceImpl {
      @Autowired
      private DAOInterface dao;

      // Rest of code
    }
```

Spring knows - to create the instance of this ServiceImpl it needs to inject a concrete impl of DAOInterface type. In case you have concrete implementation, it does so. In case you have multiple impls - you need to define by bean name which implementation you need using @Qualifier.

Interface is kind of a contract for your impl classes. Other than abstracting the actual impl, it helps you decoupling the layers by not directly having a dependency on the concrete classes. This is a good design pattern